# If the group of units of a unital ring is cyclic, must it be finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, cyclic-groups

Suppose you have a ring $R$ with $1$ and that the multiplicative subgroup $R^\times$ of $R$ is cyclic.

Is then $R^\times$ a finite group?

Are there conditions, such that $R^\times$ is cyclic, or is it and if then else relation between these two properties.

EDIT: Oky it is wrong! Is this true in Char $R\neq 2,1$?

Comment: Well the group of units of a field is always cyclic... this leads me to guess that $\overline{ \mathbb F_p}$ or $\mathbb Z_p$ might be helpful...?

Comment: @Scaramouche: Any *finite subgroup* of the group of units of a field is cyclic.

Comment: As already observed in the comments to the answer, for the group of units to be infinite cyclic, the ring must have characteristic $2$ (characteristic $1$ would mean the ring was trivial btw).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ring $R=\mathbb{F}_2[x,x^{-1}]$ is a counterexample (not the only one; see the comments), with
$$R^\times=\{\ldots,x^{-1},1,x,\ldots\}$$
forming an infinite cyclic group.

Comment: Isn't $x+1$ a unit in $R$?

Comment: What would you say its inverse is?

Comment: Ah my bad, got this confused with the power series ring.

Comment: Yes, it's the only one. Consider the order of $-1\in R^\times$ to conclude ${\rm char}(R)=2$. Let $R^\times=\langle a\rangle$. Then $R={\bf F}_2[a,a^{-1}]$ (one shows containment both ways). And $a$ is transcendental, since if it were algebraic then $R$ would be finite.

Comment: @anon it is not the only one. If $R$ is an integral domain, then the units in $R[x]$ are the same as those in $R$.

Comment: @Tobias: Aha, good point.

Comment: Ah, of course. The containment $R\supset{\bf F}_2[a,a^{-1}]$ can be strict.

Comment: Your argument does show that this is the minimal such ring though, so any ring with that property must be an algebra over this example with injective structure morphism. I wonder if it is easy to find a sufficient condition for such algebras (I suppose positively graded integral domain will work for example).

Comment: Is it true, if Char $R\neq 2$?